# docker compose spring boot logs

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker-compose

I'm trying to run both a spring boot app and mysql in separate docker containers and I'm having trouble debugging issues because I can't see any logs. When I run `docker-compose up` I see the start up logs (Spring Boot banner) and see the app start, but after that no more logging. I'm getting a 404 hitting one of my end points but I can't debug it without seeing the logs.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  database:
    build:
      context: ./database
    image: pensionator_db
    # set default mysql root password, change as needed
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: pensionatoruser
      MYSQL_DATABASE: pensionatordb
    # Expose port 3306 to host. Not for the application but
    # handy to inspect the database from the host machine.
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always

  appserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: app/src/main/docker/Dockerfile
    image: pensionator_app
    # mount point for application in tomcat
    # open ports for tomcat and remote debugging
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8000:8000"
    restart: always
```

How do I get logging to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with the logging, the issue was with my docker-compose.yml file. I needed to link the database correctly.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:

  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: pensionator
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'
    restart: always

  appserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/main/docker/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - database
    image: pensionator_app
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: 'jdbc:mysql://database:3306/pensionator'
    links:
      - database
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '8000:8000'
    restart: always
```